# Can I use 5v 5A power supply for 5v 3A circuit

Tags: power-supply

I have a dev board which came without power supply. As per the spec, it works on 5V 3A.
I have a spare power supply 5V 5A, can it be used here?

Will there be any issue?

Comment: To quote Olin's reply from the linked question "If Johnny wants to eat two apples, he's only going to eat two whether you put 2, 3, 5, or 20 apples on the table". It's the same with the current required by a load and the available supply current.

Answer (score 2):

If the power supply really can deliver 5A, then there won't likely be any issue.